# ADALM-PLUTO SDR with gnuradio on Macbook

Tags: gnuradio, software-defined-radio

I am looking to interface PlutoSDR with gnuradio on a macbook. I have gnuradio-companion installed, however, plutosdr blocks (source and sink) don't show up in it. Also tried installing iio-oscilloscope but didn't seem to work.
Online help for gnuradio+PlutoSDR+macbook is limited compared to Linux, Windows etc. platforms.
Is there anyone who has successfully made PlutoSDR work with gnuradio or iio-oscilloscope on a macbook? Please outline the steps. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried asking in gnuradio's mailing list?

Comment: Ask analog device e2z discussion forum